# Force File (PDF) Download in Laravel 4

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-4

I'm trying to force a file download, so when the user click the button, a PDF is generated automatically with data from my DB, and download. I'm using the repository pdf-l4 from thujohn.

Here is my code in the controller

```
public function downloadPDF($id) {

   $document = Document::find($id);

   $pdf =  '<html><body>'. $document->title . '<br />'. $document->body . '</body></html>';

   return PDF::load($pdf, 'A4', 'portrait')->download($document->title);

}
```

How can I access that function from my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done...

DocumentsController.php

```
public function downloadPDF($id) {

   $document = Document::find($id);

   $pdf =  '<html><body>'. $document->title . '<br />'. $document->body . '</body></html>';

   return PDF::load($pdf, 'A4', 'portrait')->download($document->title);

}
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('pdf/{id}', 'DocumentsController@downloadPDF');
```

profile.php

```
   <a href="{{ URL::to('pdf', $document->id )}}" class='btn btn-xs btn-warning'>
  PDF</a>
```

If there is a better way, please be welcome :)

Comment: Hi! Which plugin are u using t call PDF::load(...)? thanks in advance ;)